# Cannot remove startup volume from Spotlight exclude elements in Spotlight Preferences

Tags: spotlight

In `System Preferences` > `Spotlight` > `Privacy`

lately my MBP startup Volume is being added to the list of folders and volumes to be excluded from indexing.

No matter if I remove it from the list: as I close the Preference Pane and reopen it I find again the statup Volume added to the list.

On the terminal `sudo mdutil -s /` returns `Indexing enabled`

However **Mail.app** refuses to make searches as it states that indexing is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just a reboot fixed the issue.

Comment: Really ought to be amongst the first things to try for many issues. Therefore +1 here for discovering that, but -1 on the question for not trying it before asking. ;)